# Display PDF file without download in Amazon S3 in android

Tags: java, android, pdf, amazon-s3

the problem that I am currently facing is that I want to develop an Android apps that could display PDF file.

Here are my codes:

```js
public class S3Activity extends Activity {

    AmazonDynamoDB ddb;
    AmazonS3 s3;
    String bucket = "ftsmtheses";
    String destbucket = "afdal";

   public void S3Activity(String file) throws IOException{

        AmazonS3Client s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new PropertiesCredentials(CredentialsAuth.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("AwsCredentials.properties")));

            // Copying object
            CopyObjectRequest copyObjRequest = new CopyObjectRequest(
                    bucket, file, destbucket, file);
            System.out.println("Copying object.");
            s3client.copyObject(copyObjRequest);
       System.out.println("Done copying object.");

       ResponseHeaderOverrides override = new ResponseHeaderOverrides();
       override.setContentType("application/pdf");


           GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest =
                   new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(destbucket, file);
           generatePresignedUrlRequest.setMethod(HttpMethod.GET);

           URL url = s3client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
           System.out.println(url);

       try{
           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url.toURI().toString()));
           startActivity(intent);
       }catch (URISyntaxException u){

       }
```

Amazon S3 is what I use to store the PDF file, and I already have the URL. I use this:

```js
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url.toURI().toString()));
           startActivity(intent);
```

but it returns me errors. I tried to search for the solution but failed. Is the any way that I could do to overcome this problem?

```js
08-11 10:50:33.789  22050-22068/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 10:50:33.799  22050-22068/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3532)
08-11 10:50:33.799  22050-22068/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3458)
08-11 10:50:33.799  22050-22068/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3780)
08-11 10:50:33.799  22050-22068/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3748)
08-11 10:50:33.799  22050-22068/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at com.example.user.test2.S3Activity.S3Activity(S3Activity.java:57)
08-11 10:50:33.799  22050-22068/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at com.example.user.test2.MainActivity$Task.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:103)
08-11 10:50:33.799  22050-22068/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at com.example.user.test2.MainActivity$Task.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:78)
08-11 10:50:33.799  22050-22068/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
08-11 10:50:33.799  22050-22068/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-11 10:50:33.799  22050-22068/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
08-11 10:50:33.799  22050-22068/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-11 10:50:33.799  22050-22068/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-11 10:50:33.799  22050-22068/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: use Google Docs Viewer: `https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=[PDF..url..here]` load it into a webview with JavaScript enabled

Comment: ok I will definitely try this. I will get to you when i am done. ;)

Comment: Did you find the solution ? If yes, please share it.